How to exclude div classes 'modal-content' and 'modal-body' from pyppeteer web scraper?
I'm building a scraper that gets text data from a list of articles. A common specimen in the text content I'm scraping at the minute is that at the bottom there is this message:
"As a subscriber, you are shown 80% less display advertising when reading our articles. Those ads you do see are predominantly from local businesses promoting local services. These adverts enable local businesses to get in front of their target audience – the local community. It is important that we continue to promote these adverts as our local businesses need as much support as possible during these challenging times."
I want the pyppeteer scraper to ignore the classes that contain this message so that it doesn't pull into the resulting data. Looking at the site 'soup' e.g. for this url 'https://www.wimbledonguardian.co.uk/news/national/uk-today/24147538.often-replace-boiler-7-signs-look/':
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="sp-modal" class="modal" id="adlight-explanation-modal" role="dialog" style="display: none" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<img id="adlight-explanation-modal-main-logo" loading="lazy" src="/resources/responsive-static/images/love-local.png"/>
<p>As a subscriber, you are shown <strong>80% less</strong> display advertising when reading our articles.</p>
<p>Those ads you do see are predominantly from <strong>local businesses</strong> promoting <strong>local services</strong>. </p>
<p>These adverts enable local businesses to get in front of their target audience – the <strong>local community</strong>.</p>
<img id="adlight-explanation-modal-image" src="/resources/images/pixel/" style="display: none"/>
<p class="italic">It is important that we continue to promote these adverts as our local businesses need as much support as possible during these challenging times.</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="mar-btn mar-btn--dark" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>

it seems like they're stored in <div class="modal-content"> and <div class="modal-body"> but I can't seem to exclude these from the scrape. Here's a snippet of my Pyppeteer script.
if url.startswith('www.'):
            url = 'https://' + url
        try:
            page = await browser.newPage()

        await stealth(page)

        # Go to the desired page and wait for resources to load
        await page.goto(url, waitUntil='networkidle2', timeout=1000000)

        # Execute JavaScript to remove unwanted elements
        await page.evaluate('''() => {

            // Function to block new windows (pop-ups)
            function blockPopups() {
                window.open = function() {
                    console.log("Blocked a popup attempt.");
                };
            }
            blockPopups();

            // Select and remove all <nav> and <footer> elements
            const unwantedElements = document.querySelectorAll('nav, footer', 'header', 'menu', 'sidebar', 'ads', 'related', 'sponsored', 'comments', 'subscribe', 'social', 'popup', 'modal', 'mainfooter', 'search-form', 'bottomAd', 'modal-dialog', 'modal-lg', 'modal-content', 'modal-body', 'modal-footer');
            unwantedElements.forEach(el => el.remove());

            // Select and remove specific <p> elements by their class combinations
            const specificParagraphs = ['p.sc-ipEyDJ.sc-dmctIk.jsPbGk.eDQUpO', 'p.sc-ipEyDJ.sc-idXgbr.jsPbGk.hBXpo', 'p.article-comments__moderation-rules-text', 'p.delete-alert__message mar-alert__message'];
            specificParagraphs.forEach(selector => {
                const el = document.querySelector(selector);
                if (el) {
                    el.remove();
                }
            });

            // Return nothing, as content extraction will be done later in Python
        }''')

        # Extract content using BeautifulSoup
        headings, paragraphs = await extract_content(page)`

What I tried:
const unwantedElements = document.querySelectorAll('nav, footer', header', menu', 'sidebar', 'ads', 'related', 'sponsored', 'comments', subscribe', social', 'popup', 'modal', 'mainfooter', 'search-form', bottomAd', 'modal-dialog', 'modal-lg', 'modal-content', 'modal-body', modal-footer');
                unwantedElements.forEach(el => el.remove());

What I expected:
(Textual content of page without content about advertising)
What actually resulted:
(Textual content) followed by 'As a subscriber, you are shown 80% less display advertising when reading our articles. Those ads you do see are predominantly from local businesses promoting local services. These adverts enable local businesses to get in front of their target audience – the local community. It is important that we continue to promote these adverts as our local businesses need as much support as possible during these challenging times.'

Without a URL there's no way to reproduce the problem and definitively help. Please at least show the HTML. class="modal-body" is matched by .modal-body, not modal-body, which would match <modal-body></modal-body>.  Pyppeteer already lets you extract content so there's no need to use BS, it's an extra dependency and work for no benefit.

You can skip these by checking if they're a descendant of .modal-content or .modal-body
change:
unwantedElements.forEach(el => el.remove());

to:
unwantedElements.forEach(el => {
  if(!el.closest('.modal-content,.modal-body')){
    el.remove()
  }
});


This didn't appear to work, maybe they're not a descendent of either?
